Laravel Bpost API : unable create international parcel
I use Laravel 10 and the package Antidot-be/bpost-api-library
I am unable to create an international Package (example send a parcel to BE to FR : at client home)
I get always an error like : "The delivery method bpack BUSINESS with product group bpack World Express Pro is not valid for the country FR (receiver)"
Anyone could help me ?
protected function genBpostIntLabel()
    {
        $transporter = Transporter::find(1);

        $carrierData = [
            'reference' => 'TR_103',
            'company' => 'Company',
            'name' => 'Firstname Lastname',
            'address1' => 'Rue de xxx',
            'number' => '3',
            'zip' => '88120',
            'city' => 'Charmes',
            'country' => 'FR',
            'phone' => 'xxxxxx',
            'email' => 'xxx@gmail.com'
        ];

        if($transporter)
        {
            try
            {
                $apiUrl = "https://api-parcel.bpost.be/services/shm/";
                $orderReference = $carrierData['reference'];

                $bpost = new Bpost($transporter->api_key, $transporter->api_secret, $apiUrl);

                $receiverAddress = new Address();
                $receiverAddress->setStreetName($carrierData['address1']);
                $receiverAddress->setNumber($carrierData['number']);
                $receiverAddress->setPostalCode($carrierData['zip']);
                $receiverAddress->setLocality($carrierData['city']);
                $receiverAddress->setCountryCode($carrierData['country']);

                $receiver = new Receiver();
                $receiver->setAddress($receiverAddress);

                if($carrierData['company']){
                    $receiver->setCompany($carrierData['company']);
                }

                $receiver->setName($carrierData['name']);
                $receiver->setPhoneNumber($carrierData['phone']);
                $receiver->setEmailAddress($carrierData['email']);

                $box = new Box();

                $customsInfo = new Box\CustomsInfo\CustomsInfo();
                $customsInfo->setParcelValue(700);
                $customsInfo->setContentDescription('FASHION');
                $customsInfo->setShipmentType(Bpost\Order\Box\CustomsInfo\CustomsInfo::CUSTOM_INFO_SHIPMENT_TYPE_GOODS);
                $customsInfo->setParcelReturnInstructions(Bpost\Order\Box\CustomsInfo\CustomsInfo::CUSTOM_INFO_PARCEL_RETURN_INSTRUCTION_RTS);
                $customsInfo->setPrivateAddress(false);

                $international = new Box\International();
                $international->setProduct(Bpost\ProductConfiguration\Product::PRODUCT_NAME_BPACK_WORLD_EXPRESS_PRO);
                $international->setReceiver($receiver);
                $international->setParcelWeight(2000);
                $international->setCustomsInfo($customsInfo);

                $box->setInternationalBox($international);

                $order = new Bpost\Order($orderReference);
                $order->addBox($box);

                $bpost->createOrReplaceOrder($order);

                $labels = $bpost->createLabelForOrder(
                    $orderReference,
                    Bpost::LABEL_FORMAT_A6,
                    false,
                    true
                );

                foreach ($labels as $label) {
                    $barcode = $label->getBarcode();
                    $bytes = $label->getBytes();

                    $local = Storage::disk('public');
                    $local->put('labels/bpost/'.$barcode.'.pdf', $bytes, 'public');
                }

                dd(json_encode(['provider' => 'bpost', 'tracking' => $barcode, 'file' => $barcode.'.pdf']));
            }
            catch (\Exception $e) {
                dd($e->getMessage());
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

